# NoReverseMatch when using {% url %} in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am following a book (Practical Django Projects 2nd Ed.), and I have run across an error that I cannot figure out.

I get this error:
TemplateSyntaxError at /weblog/

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'coltrane_category_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Here is the code in my template that uses {% url %}:

```
    <li id="main-nav-entries">
        <a href="{% url coltrane_entry_archive_index %}">Entries</a>
    </li>
```

Here is my URL configuration:

```
entry_info_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
}

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
    (r'^$', 'archive_index', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_index'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'archive_year', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_year'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$', 'archive_month', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_month'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$', 'archive_day', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_archive_day'),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', entry_info_dict, 'coltrane_entry_detail'),
)
```

What does the error mean? Am I not giving it enough arguments? How does the {% url %} work? From my understanding, it will look at the URL configuration and find the matching keywords and give back a URL based on the matching keyword in the URL configuration.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use the `url` function on your patten for it to register that pattern's name properly.  See the [Django documentation on naming url patterns](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).

Basically, change your patterns to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.date_based',
    url(r'^$', 'archive_index', entry_info_dict, name='coltrane_entry_archive_index'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 'archive_year', entry_info_dict, name='coltrane_entry_archive_year'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/$', 'archive_month', entry_info_dict, name='coltrane_entry_archive_month'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$', 'archive_day', entry_info_dict, name='coltrane_entry_archive_day'),
    url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail', entry_info_dict, name='coltrane_entry_detail'),
)
```

I think it works without using `name=` as a named arg but I always prefer to because it's more explicit to me.